# Android Room DB Migration

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, database-migration

Problem - Room DB getting wiped/cleared when doing force update play store update. I am working on a chat messenger application which uses Room DB as local database. Whenever I do a store update with increasing DB version, the local DB gets cleared and messages history are lost.

I'm Using Room DB. My Application is in the Play Store with the use of Room DB and the version is 4.

My Question is I'm changing the 9 tables schema, and now that I update the DB version, each table schema changes. Should I increase the DB version here? How can I accomplish this without losing the user data using Room DB for force update in Play Store? Ex. DB version is 4, I change the two tables’ elements like in the below query.

Do I need to increase DB version twice as two tables are changed or change to one number incremental will be fine? Example:  Do I need DB to increase version to 6 OR keeping it 5 is enough?

```
private val mMigrationMessageStatus: Migration = object : Migration(4, 5) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE message_status RENAME TO MessageStatus")
                database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE MessageStatus ADD COLUMN userId TEXT NOT NULL default ''")
            }
        }
 private val mMigrationGroupMember: Migration = object : Migration(4, 5) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE group_member RENAME TO GroupMember")
                database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE GroupMember ADD COLUMN userId TEXT NOT NULL default ''")
            }
        }


return Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, dbName)
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .addMigrations(mMigrationMessageStatus,mMigrationGroupMember)
                .build()
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions#automigrationspec) Since you are renaming the table, ambiguity should be handled. Read [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-migrations-with-room-f01e04b07929) as well.

Comment: If i add automigration then i will skip the queries and adding migrations to builder is avoided or must also give in builder.

Comment: it doesn't matter how many changes you are going to make in DB of your new build just increment one number will be fine. but make sure you handle the behaviour or DB changes. because some columns or fields might be null or empty.

Comment: I execute All the queries and i check with internal app testing also but one by one i change the table and test it will work fine. But all the table changes made and db version will be incremental for the each 9 tables then put internal testing is not working. This is an issue Asad.

Answer (score 0):

From **room version 2.4.0**, you can easily update using autoMigrations.

DATABASE CLASS

```
@Database(
    version = 3,
    autoMigrations = [
        AutoMigration(from = 1, to = 2),
        AutoMigration(from = 2, to = 3)
    ],
    .....
)
```

DATA CLASS

```
@Entity(tableName = "user")
data class DataUser(
    ....
    // I added this column, like this
    @ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "")var test: String = ""  
)
```

see reference below

[android developer: room version2.4.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#version_240_3)

[android developer: autoMigration](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/AutoMigration)

Comment: okay, That link is what I put in another answer. I deleted the link and put the same answer back here.

Comment: how to write unit testing for auto migration?

Comment: use MigrationTestHelper class.
check android document [https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions?hl=ko#single-migration-test]